# Running BizTalk 2020 developer edition as a cluster on Azure VM

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2020

Is there any licensing restriction on running a non-production BizTalk 2020 clustered environment with Developer Edition?

I'm aware that Developer edition has all the features similar to Enterprise edition and can be used for non-production environments, but I couldn't find any answers which indicates licesning restrictions using this setup.

I've checked this [Mircosoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/use-windows-cluster-to-provide-high-availability-for-biztalk-hosts) about '**Using Windows Server Cluster to Provide High Availability for BizTalk Server Hosts2**', which says '**Host clustering is only available with BizTalk Server Enterprise Edition.**', but I have discussed this with one of our BizTalk experts and he is saying that using Developer edition in a clustered environment is completely fine, but I do not want our customers to get into any licensing violations. I will appreciate it if I can get some help on finding appropriate references for this particular use-case of BizTalk Developer edition.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because licencing is off-topic

Comment: The only licencing for BizTalk Sever Developer editions that I'm aware of is that those that use it have MSDN licences, and that it isn't used for Production purposes

Comment: @Dijkgraaf any suggestions on where I should post my question on licensing?

Comment: Probably the Microsoft forum.  e.g like this question which is also asking about Developer Edition and clustering  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/671320/biztalk-cluster-with-2020-developer-edition.html